# Python - Save CSV file in UTF-16LE

Tags: python, csv

I have to import som data to my Yahoo Marketing account - and the CSV file has to be encoding in - yahoo:  CSV/TSV files: Unicode (technically UTF-16LE encoding)

```
writer = csv.writer(open('new_yahoo.csv','w', encoding='utf-16-le'), delimiter="\t")
writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: This isn't really a question... I answered what I think you wanted (can it be done with Python's csv.writer) but you really need to explain exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down on the examples provided in the Python CSV [page](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples), you'll find that it

> The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode, but it is 8-bit-clean save for some problems with ASCII NUL characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.

But if you do need to do unicode, it looks like this could help:

> unicode_csv_reader() below is a generator that wraps csv.reader to handle Unicode CSV data (a list of Unicode strings).
>
> ...
>
> For all other encodings the following UnicodeReader and UnicodeWriter classes can be used. They take an additional encoding parameter in their constructor and make sure that the data passes the real reader or writer encoded as UTF-8:

So it looks like the example they provide at the bottom should do the encoding you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Python 3.X judging by the `open` command used.  What you have should work, although you may need to define the `newline` parameter as well.  `newline=''` will use the native line ending (CRLF on Windows, for example), but Yahoo may have other requirements.  The code below generated the file correctly on Windows with CRLF line endings.

```
data = [
    ['One','Two','Three'],
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]]

import csv
f = open('new_yahoo.csv','w', newline='', encoding='utf-16-le')
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerows(data)
f.close()
```